# How to get HTTP response in PhantomJS with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, phantomjs

I am trying to open a URL through selenium and phantomJS using python. How to get HTTP response code in PhantomJS with python. So if the status code is 200, only then processing should continue, else it should stop there.

Comment: Do you mean through selenium or through subprocess?

Comment: That's something you would need to do in javascript.